# If I console log these values I get them why does it return an empty object

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using dynamic forms to retrieve these values from my form when I console log new student it returns and empty object but when I console log each individual this.student.Student_Name, this.student.Student_Number, this.student.Student_Surname it gives me 3 seperate values. Also Student_ID is 0 by default always

```
student = {
Student_ID: 0,
Student_Name: '',
Student_Number: 0,
Student_Surname: '',
};

onSubmitStudent() {
this.student.Student_Name = this.studentsForm.value.studentData.Student_Name;
this.student.Student_Number = this.studentsForm.value.studentData.Student_Number;
this.student.Student_Surname = this.studentsForm.value.studentData.Student_Surname;
const newStudent = new Student(
  this.student.Student_ID,
  this.student.Student_Name,
  this.student.Student_Number,
  this.student.Student_Surname
);

console.log(newStudent)
newStudent returns empty.


export class Student {
public Student_ID: number;
public Student_Name: string;
public Student_Number: number;
public Student_Surname: string;

constructor(
Student_ID: number,
Student_Name: string,
Student_Number: number,
Student_Surname: string
) {
Student_ID = Student_ID;
Student_Name = Student_Name;
Student_Number = Student_Number;
Student_Surname = Student_Surname;
}
}
```

Comment: Did you check the values by displaying form's value? For example, console.log(form.value)?

Comment: You have to debug the constructor in the class, to see if the values are coming and if they are sett, try to use `this` or maybe getters and setters.

Comment: Sheki I just had to use this. in my constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign values in constructer using this keyword

```
constructor(
    Student_ID: number,
    Student_Name: string,
    Student_Number: number,
    Student_Surname: string
) {
    this.Student_ID = Student_ID;
    this.Student_Name = Student_Name;
    this.Student_Number = Student_Number;
    this.Student_Surname = Student_Surname;
}
}
```